# Xamarin Binding ViewCell

Tags: xamarin.forms

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CardItems[0]}" RowHeight="100">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CardItemTapCommand}" />
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="64"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

My view has its binding context set to the corresponding viewmodel.
My CardItemTapCommand doesn't work.(i think this is happening because the binding context of each viewcell is the cardItem[0] list). Is setting the binding context of the cell to the viewmodel again a bad idea?

Comment: use a relative binding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? If the answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
<ContentPage ... 
             x:Name="PageName">

   <ContentPage.Content>
       ...
       <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, 
           Source={x:Reference PageName}}"/>
       </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
       ...
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```